# 'The label SRID=4326;POINT( in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid.'

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, gis, geospatial

A combination of abstract programming, poor/incomplete documentation, and cryptic errors have left me scratching my head to figure out what is causing this error:

- MySql 5.6
- Entity Framework 6.0.2
- MySql Connector for .NET 6.8.3

Simply using EntityFramework to load models from a table that has a geometry column. The value of the column was set by:

```
var example = DbGeometry.FromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", 51.5 /* Lat /*, -1.28 /* LON * /), 4326)
```

Reading the value back generates the exception:

> 24114: The label SRID=4326;POINT(51.5 in the input well-known text
>   (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON,
>   MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,
>   CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography
>   Data Type only).

With a stacktrace:

```
[FormatException: 24114: The label SRID=4326;POINT(51.5 in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type only).]
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisTypes.ParseLabel(String input) +326
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type) +99
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid) +47
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid) +485
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.Parse(SqlString s) +222
```

My first observation is the use of Microsoft.SqlServer namespace which seems inconsistent since I'm using the MySQL provider.

Does the MySQL .NET Connector not support SRIDs?  Has it not registered properly?  (Basically I'm trying to work out what units the .`Distance()` method on a `DbGeometry` object is returning, so far it seems to be a random decimal.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer to your question and i'm not entirely sure why you're getting the error, but I had some advice and it was too long for comments.

You need to specify Longitude before Latitude when creating the point.  Your coordinates are technically valid either way given their values, but of course you will experience issues in other regions and if you ever mapped it, that coordinate would not be in the UK where you'd expect with the sample coordinates.

Additionally, if you know it's a point, use the DbGeometry.PointFromText(WKT, SRID) method - it's just easier to read.

```
double lng = -1.28;
double lat = 51.5;
var wkt = String.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lng, lat);
var geometry = DbGeometry.PointFromText(wkt, 4326);
```

I'd also recommend using Geography rather than Geometry if you're using a latitude / longitude system - or is there a specific reason for using Geometry?  The methods above are available in DbGeography.

**Edit: The unit (or random decimal as you put it) for STDistance() is in metres.**

Good luck in finding the source of the error.

Comment: Thanks for input Jon. I'm using DbGeometry as DbGeography won't map to a column type (MySql).  I switched lng and lat, but still get the error (couldn't find any documentation on this).  As for units in meters, when combined with a where clause, the query wouldn't match. I.e (distance x 100) = 5km, then do where (distance <= (5/100)) and the record would not be found - puzzling. I think I'll just give up and use the 'old fashioned' way and write the SQL manually, skipping Entity Framework completely. Hard work all round, wasted all day on this. I've found the .NET connector unreliable at best.

Comment: @simbolo you're welcome.  Such a shame that you've got MySQL to deal with as SQL-Server really does an amazing job with Spatial and EF5+.  I'm not sure I follow on the distance clause you mentioned though, writing `WHERE geom.STDistance < (5/100)` would try to find anything within 5cm.  Perhaps i'm just not seeing pas a typo so late in the day!  Best of luck.

Comment: I think you need to just strip the SRID out and try that.  Some spatial systems don't really support it in the wkt form.  Your units will just be implied by which datum/projection you are using (meters in this case).